# Select DropDown option using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

If someone could help me with this mystery.. Here is the [url](https://www.schoolofdragons.com/Parents/ActivateAccount.aspx?key=bop15Gn9jl9MCWB369XU5fPJoFrOjtdhjU3bZ5pbB0bqyFTvVTNM8BqlLbGCl%2fDXOMKADtPwUQFJ21IfnTdwT2cMayD739a9eKS%2fPqODwTuYz61Vk8H4Iu%2fzcjg1x0q%2bfNaTfaeLqb%2fMLwRE%2b859cw%3d%3d&lang=en-US)

Here if you can see the Date of Birth Fields I am able to select the Month and Date but I am not able to select Year 
I Tried selecting Using Value, Index it did not work the same code worked for Month and Date

Below is My Code:

```
WebElement W = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form[@id='aspnetForm'][contains(@action,'ActivateAccount.aspx?key=')][@method='post'][@name='aspnetForm']/div[@class='border4']/div[@id='page']/div[@class='IE-SCroll-mid']/div/div[@class='change-info-contain']/div/div/div/label[3]/select"));     
Select dropdown = new Select(W);
dropdown.selectByValue("1997");
```

Comment: Can you provide the `code` you tried with?

Comment: Works for me, though you really shouldn't be putting links like that in a question. Put your code, explain the problem.

Comment: I have added my code :) currently ended up using auto it to select only year it ... if some 1 could try if selecting the field works ....

Comment: Why don't you just simply use the `ctl00_mcp_ddlYear` as id to identify the element. Your `xpath` is doing lot of work which does not have to

Comment: Yes .. I did try just using the page object .. it did not work.. ended up trying all sort of options ... no luck with it

Comment: @SubramanyaKrishnaBaliga And, just simply saying did not work does not give us enough info to troubleshoot your problem. Please provide stacktrace with the explanation why and what does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing `explicit` wait with that. That will make sure the elemenet is present before start looking for that.

```
By byId = By.id("ctl00_mcp_ddlYear");

//use explicit wait to make sure the element is there
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byId));

Select dropdown = new Select(myDynamicElement);
dropdown.selectByValue("1997");
```

You can also use the `cssSelector` directly wait for the specific option to be present with the following code

```
//explicit wait
By byCss = By.cssSelector("#ctl00_mcp_ddlYear>option[value='1997']");
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byCss));
element.click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saifur it worked :) i feel the explicit wait made it work